# Question regarding binomial and bernoulli notation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, binomial-distribution, notation, bernoulli-distribution

I have a bunch of independent binary variables Xk where k >= 1
and P[Xk = x] = 1/4^u * 3/4^(1-u) for u = 0 or u = 1 ... this is a bernoulli distribution, right?

I'm confused on whether I should label Xk ~ Binomial(1,1/4) or ~ Bernoulli(1/4)

Is there a difference or am I just making this way more complicated than it needs to be? thank you in advance for your help and sorry for this simple question

Comment: The test is to compare the probabilities implied by the two notations: if they give the same probabilities across the board for all possible outcomes, then they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can label it either way; a Bernoulli(1/4) random variable is identically distributed with a Binomial(1, 1/4) random variable. It makes no difference. How you label it would depend on context.